# Using Web Services with Database Mysql in java

Tags: web-services, web-applications

can any one please tell me how i can use Mysql with web services . i want to save and retrieve data  from mysql. please suggest any good tutorial for that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a platform, so I suppose that is open for you?  That is a very broad question as well.

This is an excellent tutorial which should get you quickly started, step by step, using Glassfish (free from Sun/Oracle), Java, and MySQL to build web services to query the database (which is exactly what you asked for):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/GFandMySQL_Part3.html

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot account for links posted in 2012.